# How do I read the contents of the network shortcuts folder in C#?

Tags: c#, directory, shortcut

My network shortcuts folder is located here:

C:\Users\elan\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts

This folder contains a number of shortcuts to web folders that I defined/configured. These are visible in Window Explorer. How do I get a directory listing of this folder to the shortcut files in code? I tried the below, but it returns no files:

```
string path = @"C:\Users\elan\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts";
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
```

Comment: Just to make sure - the shortcuts aren't hidden, and you have permission to access that folder?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I thought the Network Shortcuts folder works based on an Explorer extension that reads the information from the registry. The folder is actually there but Windows is playing some games to make it look like there are files in there when there aren't.

Comment: It turns out the entries are directories...

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the entries in the Network Shortcuts folder are not files but are directories. The following worked:

```
string path = @"C:\Users\elan\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts";
string[] dirs  = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
```